# What does curly brackets do in Xpath?

Tags: c#, xpath

I am reading a legacy framework written in C#, there is a constant string defined as following:

```
private const string NAVBAR_PANEL_TEMPLATE = 
   ".//*[@id='navbar']//*[contains(@class, 'platform-nav-{0}')]";
```

This string is to be used for element-searching by xpath. To my understanding, it can be translated as: "looking for elements whose ids are equal to 'navbar', under those matching elements, looking for elements whose class contains 'platform-nav-{0}'".

I am really confused by the last {0}, what does it represent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely not part of the XPath expression. The code is likely passing `NAVBAR_PANEL_TEMPLATE` to `String.Format()` and substituting a value in place of `{0}`.

Comment: +one, but XPath expression

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk You are correct. Doing too many things at once. Thanks for pointing it out.